# Calling GetKeyState in a tight loop, why doesn't it work?

Tags: winapi

In Charles Petzold's book "Programming Windows", he mentioned the following:

"Be careful with GetKeyState. It is not a real-time keyboard status check. Rather it reflects the keyboard status up to and including the current message being processed."

"Do not do `while(GetKeyState(VK_F1) >= 0);`", it is guaranteed to hang your program.

I don't understand these at all. Could someone give an explanation for these two facts, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you read a queued keyboard message, for example by calling `GetMessage`, the OS updates private keyboard state data associated with the calling thread. When you call `GetKeyState`  that private keyboard state data is used to determine the returned key state. Thus, so long as you don't read another queued message, `GetKeyState` will always return the same value.